# PHP best method to affect variables in a function

Tags: php

I'm playing around with hooking into functions, the hook will call the method of another object, what is the best way of changing the value $price in the parent function before it is returned?

```
function _product_price ($price,$taxable = true)
{
    $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_BEFORE');
    $price = 100.00;
    $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_AFTER');
    return number_format($price,2);
}
```

Thanks guys, would this be a suitable solution?

```
function _product_price ($price,$taxable = true)
{
    global $shop;
    $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_BEFORE');
    $price = 100.00;
    $shop->passedArgs['price'] = $price;
    $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_AFTER');
    return number_format($shop->passedArgs['price'],2);
}
function _hook ()
{
    global $shop;
    $shop->passedArgs['price'] = 23.00;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I should mention that I may choose to return more than one value or none at all. Without working through an array of returned values $price = $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_AFTER'); wouldn't be much use.

Answer (score 2):

Since you likely want to register arbitrary methods for hooks, have a look at

- [Subject/Observer](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) and
- [Event Dispatcher](http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass the variables to the point either:

- as an array of references, (`array('price' => &$price);` would make any change to the `$var['price']` variable in a function later on / deeper reflect in the 'in-scope' `$price`.
- set the variables to the point as an object-property and just pass the current observable object as a parameter.

Comment: It _can_ work, but I'd hardly call it suitable. `passedArgs` should not be needed in any decent hook/observer system, in about 99% of cases they should be 'natural' properties of objects. Also introducing globals seems a bit off, usually an observer object is added as a property to a subject/observable.

Comment: I've seen the light! You're right, I'm only ever working with one product object at a time so I just altered the object directly within the hook. Then I don't need to return anything.

 `function _product_price ($price,$taxable = true)
 {
     global $shop;
     $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_BEFORE');
     // Default price process
     $shop->product->price = 100.00;
     $shop->_hook('PRODUCT_PRICE_AFTER');
 }
 function _hook ()
 {
     global $shop;
     $shop->product->price = 23.00;
 }`